# What does __typeof(&*self) in Objective-C mean? How does it differ from __typeof(self)?

Tags: objective-c

I was looking through some MVVM sample code and run into this line:

```
__weak __typeof(&*self) weakSelf = self;
/*later used in some block*/
```

I understand what `__weak` and `typeof(self)` are for. Why not just use `__weak __typeof(self)` or `__weak ViewController *weakSelf`? What are the reference and asterisk (`&*self`) being used for?

Comment: Pointers work the same way in Objective-C as they do in standard C.  So `&*self` is the same as `self`, and `__typeof(self)` works as expected in this case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah, I see that it works, just wondering what &* there are for, thanks for response! It's like *self dereferences the self pointer and & is a reference of it? I'm confused

Comment: "*It's like *self dereferences the self pointer and & is a reference of it?*" - yes, exactly. `*self` dereferences the `self` pointer to get at the object, and then `&` gets the address of the object, the same address that `self` is pointing at.

Comment: @RemyLebeau now I fully understood why `&*self` and `self` are same things. Thank you a lot!

Comment: No difference. However, earlier LLVM does not accept `__typeof(self)`, so these ARC users use `__typeof(&*self)` instead to workaround the compilation issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*&` is a C++-ism.  It is used to pass by reference pointer parameters.

`&*` looks like someone was very confused and ended up writing code that is effectively a no-op.  However, if that is Objective-C++ code, then `&*` might very well do something (iirc, smart pointers can end up requiring weird indirection usage to do certain things).

Most of the projects I work on use `__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
__weak __typeof(&*self)weakSelf = self;

__weak HomeVC *weakSelf2 = self;

NSLog(@"%@", weakSelf);  // This gives you the reference of the View Controller Object
NSLog(@"%p", weakSelf);  // This gives you only the address of the View Controller Object
NSLog(@"%@", weakSelf2); // Same as 1
NSLog(@"%p", weakSelf2); // Same as 2
NSLog(@"%@", &*self);    // Same as 1
NSLog(@"%p", &*self);    // Same as 2

// In the above logs you can notice the difference just by changing the format specifier. Hope this helps.
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, but only points out the difference between %p and %@, which is unrelated.